# Power analysis for non-inferiority study

Tags: statistical-power, non-inferiority

I'm doing a power analysis for a non-inferiority study based on this calculation from "Sample size calculations in clinical research" by Chow, Shao, Wang, and Lokhnygina:

$$
n = \frac{(z_{\alpha}+z_{\beta})^2}{(\epsilon-\delta)^2}\left[p_1(1-p_1)+p_2(1-p_2)\right]
$$

where $p_1$ refers to treatment, and $p_2$ refers to control, $\epsilon$ is the assumed true difference $p_1-p_2$ and $\delta$ is the margin of inferiority (it is negative). My question is, how to choose $\epsilon$? Usually in any power analysis, we try to specify the minimum effect size we care about detecting, and in this case, $\delta$ takes that role. I am not at all sure about how to specify $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in:

> ϵ is the assumed true difference p1−p2 and δ is the margin of inferiority (it is negative).

However, your interpretation:

> Usually in any power analysis, we try to specify the minimum effect size we care about detecting, and in this case, δ takes that role.

is incorrect.

δ is the margin of inferiority, it is the clinically meaningful amount of inferiority the experiments are willing to tolerate (this is usually based on clinical opinion or FDA guideline has a formula for deriving it from existing evidence from studies of the active control).

ϵ is the effect size, in the setting of power analysis for proportions, it is the minimum true difference between p1 and p2 that you would like to detect.

In the context of non-inferiority study, ϵ could be a negative value. The smaller the value for ϵ (which means a negative value closer to δ) is, the larger the sample size will be needed to achieve the same power.

Comment: For non-Bayesian statistics, p1 and p2 are fixed constant as parameters waiting to be estimated. So their difference is also a constant. Then 'the minimum true difference' is incorrect.

Comment: @user158565 You are correct about the Frequentist view that all these parameters are constants. However "the minimum true difference to detect" is still a valid concept. We have to assume a value of this true difference (an unknown constant) when we calculate power. We could give our best guesses or give out values based on content knowledge before knowing the true value, thus "minimum" is still a valid concept within our guesses/opinions.

Comment: "best guesses or give out values based on content knowledge" = "the minimum true difference to detect"?